# Why sizeof of char* allocated with malloc return 8?

Tags: g++, malloc, sizeof

I'm compiling with g++.

I have this code:

`char* charP = (char*) malloc(1);`

I understood it as allocate 1 byte.

When I do a `printf` for the size of `charP` it shows 8.

`printf("size of charP is %lu \n", sizeof(charP));`

Why is it 8 instead of 1?

Answer (score 1):

sizeof(charP) returns the bytesize of the pointer, not of the buffer referenced to by this pointer. Since you are on a 64-bit machine, the size of charP is 8 bytes.

The best way to get the length of the buffer is to just remember it. (you know you allocated 1 byte)